# Ruby plugin in logstash not working

Tags: ruby, logstash, logstash-configuration

The ruby filter inside ruby filter raises an error at =>. I'm confused on how to make it work. I am  supposed to remove fields from log files which has many json objects. I am removing the entries with very long keys.

```
 input {
 file {
type => "syslog"

# Wildcards work, here :)
path => ["C:\Users\ppurush\Desktop\test\*.log"]


 }
}

filter{
ruby {
 code =>"

     keyval = [url][queryString].split('&')

            for field in keyval
                result = field.split(': ')
                key = result[0]
                if key =~ /^.{50,}$/
          ruby {
                remove_field =>"[  "[url][queryString]" ]"
                }
            end
"
    }
}

output {
  stdout { }
  elasticsearch { embedded => true }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The ruby code is surrounded by double quotes, which means you can't use double quotes *inside* the ruby code itself.

Also, try catching errors:

```
ruby {
    code => "

      begin

        # your great code goes here

      rescue Exception => e

        event['ruby_exception'] = 'YOUR_FILTER_NAME: ' + e.message

      end

   "
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats a very valid answer. Double quotes with double quotes.

Comment: I cannot access [url][queryString] because it is json. Any way to go about that?

Comment: Everything is inside "event" when you're in ruby.  Try event['url']['queryString']

Comment: It also throws an error for remove_field =>"[  "[url][queryString]" ]" line at =>..